# Building instructions: Robot Spider Pen by Ricardo Oliveira

Tags: nxt

Some time ago I found the [following youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU9SaCFnCng) by Ricardo Oliveira of a small NXT plotter that crawls over a whiteboard. It has two strings that can be shortened through coils and with this, it controls its position on the whiteboard.

Here is a screenshot from the video.

[image]

The whole idea behind it is as simple as it is intriguing. I really like it. There is a somewhat more detailed video (thanks to Mr. Shiny for sharing the link) [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5x0n29MjIi8).

Nevertheless, could someone who has already recreated it and could they share detailed images (or even better a construction plan)?

Comment: I haven't seen any instructions, but here are a BrickPi version and an EV3 version that may give you some inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYG3XGfyVHk, https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/554637794684451/

Comment: There is a video which explains a little of what went into building the robot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5x0n29MjIi8

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I have already seen this video and it indeed gives more insight. I still was hoping for someone who rebuilt the model and has really detailed photos. I had some further ideas for the programming and if there was a quick way to get a working and tested model, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I thought you might have seen it, that's why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I included your link in the description of my question.